# Populating JsTree with JSON variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, jstree

I've been trying the whole day to get this thing working but somehow JsTree doesn't want to render my JSON data.

Here is the example JSON object:

```
{"parent":null, "ProductOption":null, "data":"HlaHd", "text":"global", "DelegationScope":0, "children":null, "entityId":1}
```

I get the JSON object through an AJAX call on `$(document).ready()`:

```
if ($('#ProductTree').length) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "Post",
                url: "/blah/blah",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { id : blah },
                success: function (json) {
                    createJsTree(json);
                }
            });
        }
```

And here is how I'm creating the tree:

```
function createJsTree(json) {
        $('#ProductTree').jstree({
            'core': {
                'themes': {
                    'name': 'proton',
                    'responsive': true
                },
                'check_callback': true,
                'data': json
            }
        });
    }
```

At first I thought maybe my JSON object is faulty, so I printed the object on the chrome's console right before creating the JsTree:

```
    function createJsTree(json) {
        console.log(json);
        $('#ProductTree').jstree({
            'core': {
                'themes': {
                    'name': 'proton',
                    'responsive': true
                },
                'check_callback': true,
                'data': json
            }
        });
    }
```

And the JSON object is exactly as I stated above. Now the funny thing is, if I just paste the literal JSON object as the data in JsTree creation like the following:

```
    function createJsTree(json) {
        $('#ProductTree').jstree({
            'core': {
                'themes': {
                    'name': 'proton',
                    'responsive': true
                },
                'check_callback': true,
                'data': { "parent": null, "ProductOption": null, "data": "HlaHd", "text": "global", "DelegationScope": 0, "children": null, "entityId": 1 }
            }
        });
    }
```

Then the tree gets rendered. What on earth is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to pass a string representing a json object instead of the object itself. It should work if you write `data: JSON.parse(json)` replacing `data: json`.

Comment: Oh god, that solved it. Thanks. I was going insane.

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse responded JSON string to json format using `JSON.parse()`.
Hope this will help.